# how can i link a new page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my link

```
 href="<?php echo base_url();?>views/contact"
```

controller code here

```
 class S extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('banner');
    $this->load->view('content');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}

public function contact()
{
    $this->load->view('contact');
}

}
```

my output :

> 404 Page Not Found
>    The page you requested was not found.

plese help me....

Comment: did you created view page by name contact ?

Comment: href should be controller name and function name not view folder name

Comment: try href="s/contact"

Comment: just go to the application/view folder and create the view file u want to render

Comment: try this href="<?php echo base_url();?>s/contact"

Comment: Thank You .  href="s/contact"     It worked.   thankyou very much.....

Comment: try to make it with green tick it useful to future user @RabiulIslamSohag

Answer (score 1):

href should be controller name and function name not view folder name

try this

```
href="<?php echo base_url();?>s/contact"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare the route in the config/route.php file ?
[See this link to description](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

to make custom route for a page you can add the route of page and the controller action in config/route.php as follows

```
$route['contact'] = 's/contact';
```

then you can request the page from any place as the following by using site_url() method

```
<a href="site_url('contact')">Contact</a>
```

note you need to load url helper to use this method you can autoload it in  config/autoload.php

I hope my answer would be useful